# Remove instance of reassigned variable in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, weak-references

I am trying to create a Timer class using threads that when an instance is reassigned it removes the old thread so both threads don't keep running.
Is it possible to remove old instances of a class when it is no longer referenced?

For example

```
class Timer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback, delay):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = Event()
        self.callback = callback
        self.delay = delay
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(self.delay):
            self.callback()

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped.set()
        Thread.join(self)

x = Timer(func1, 0.5)
sleep(2)
x = Timer(func2, 0.5)
sleep(5)
```

Running this code results in func1 and func2 being called during the final sleep. Is it possible when x is reassigned that the first thread is closed so that only func2 would be called. I have tried creating a class method that returns a weakref to a new Timer instance and using gc.collect() to try remove the old instance but I cannot get it to work.

Any ideas?